# Image sizes reset when changing theme

Tags: images, themes

Is there a way to prevent my image sizes in media settings from changing when I switch themes? This doesn't seem like it should be a normal thing but it is happening!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you upload an image using Media Uploader, WordPress generates various image sizes(different copies) for the picture that you upload. Go to media and find whether there are multiple images with different sizes. I guess switching themes is not a reason for changing image sizes.
[Refer this link](https://mythemeshop.com/blog/how-to-prevent-wordpress-from-generating-image-sizes/), it may help you

Comment: Yes I have the WordPress defaults image sizes (Thumbnail, Medium, Large) at the dimensions I want but when I switch to another theme the dimensions are changed. And when I change back to the other theme again they stay on the changed dimensions. So I have to manually update them whenever switching themes. A theme shouldn't save these sizes specifically for it should it? and if it does you would think when that theme is exited they will revert back again.

Comment: @MatJon it seems like one of your themes have css and/or js to resize display image sizes. look into that